# why is the valarry not getting initialized

Tags: c++

iam getting this error>
error: expected primary-expression before '[' token|

```
    #include <iostream.h>
    #include<algorithm> // for partition algorithm
    #include<vector> // for vector
    #include <valarray,h>
    using namespace std;
    int main()
    {
        valarray <int> var;
        var=var.apply([](int x){
            return x=x+1;
```

> `[Blockquote][1]`

```
        });
        cout<<var[1];
    }
```

Comment: Your `valarray` has 0 elements. To each of it's 0 elements you apply a function, and then you try to print a non-existing element.

Answer (score 0):

You should `#include <valarray>`, not `valarray,h`

Also, the `[Blockquote][1]` must be removed.

Then your code compiles, but still works on an empty array.  So when you do this:

```
cout << var[1];
```

you're trying to access an element out of bounds.  That causes undefined behavior.